# Running multiple task on launch

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the following tasks.json

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "command": "mvn",
  "isShellCommand": true,
  "args": [],
  "showOutput": "always",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskName": "compile"
    },
    {
      "taskName": "package"
    }
  ]   
}
```

And launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Java",
            "type": "java",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}", // ${fileDirname}: the current opened file's dirname
            "startupClass": "myapp.${fileBasename}", // ${fileBasename}: the current opened file's basename
            "options": [
                "-classpath",
                "${workspaceRoot}/target/classes;${workspaceRoot}/target/classes/lib/*" // ${fileDirname}: the current opened file's dirname
            ],
            "jdkPath": "${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin", // ${env.JAVA_HOME}: reference environment variables
            "preLaunchTask": "compile"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the `compile` command is pre-launched. But how can I define mutliple commands? I would like to run `package` then `compile`, not only `compile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below task definition to invoke both *compile* and *package* targets.

```
{
   "taskName": "compile",
   "args": ["-B", "package","compile"],
   "isBuildCommand": true
}
```